# Why do knowledge-based agents only add a sentence to the knowledge base when it is 100% sure the sentence is true?

Tags: logic

According to Russell and Norvig, a knowledge-based agent will only add a sentence to its knowledge base if it *follows logically* from what it previously knows, or directly observes. To *follow logically* essentially means that if the premises are true, then the conclusions are guaranteed to be true. So the agent will only add the sentence if it 100% sure the sentence is true.

Is this hyperskepticism in logic justified? Couldn't the agent be more efficient if it added a sentence if it were 99% sure it were true? It could potentially add a lot more true sentences, and only occasionally add false ones. There would need to be a mechanism for unlearning sentences, but as long as the vast majority of sentences added are true, why couldn't that be done?

I essentially asked this question [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Miscellaneous#.22Proof.22_of_the_principle_of_skepticism.3F), and someone suggested that I post it here.

Comment: Great question.  (Please link the Russell and Norvig if you get a chance.)  PS- Welcome to AI!

Answer (score 4):

Mostly because traditional "knowledge based systems" are based purely on deductive logic and that's just the way deduction works.  It only deals with what consequences *must* follow from the premises.  Traditionally these systems didn't deal with probabilistic knowledge or other less strict forms of reasoning, like abduction.

That said, it is possible to build a knowledge based system that includes probabilistic reasoning, and other reasoning systems (like abduction).

I'll add some more on that point when I have a little more time.